# Spinning wheel during startup, stuck there on 20.04 2/3 or 3/4 boots

Tags: boot, 20.04, dell

Installed 20.04 but boot fails, stalling at the spinning wheel icon.

I must restart 2-3 times to boot into my system.

What could be the problem?

Comment: If the MV was not just freshely installed, maybe it's not just "spinning". Press the "esc" button, you should see the logs: it is doing things. Don't panic and wait until the boot is done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the LiveUSB used to install Ubuntu 20.04 may have been installed with a corrupted download.

Please redownload Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download

or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .

Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu .

Make a new LiveUSB following these instructions on [another Linux PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)  or [on a Windows PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) .

Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: all instructions were done, still not working, installed 18.04 again....
tried to install on 2 different ssd's

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. A possible cause could be that the .iso file didn't download properly. I downloaded the .iso file again and it worked out this time.

Answer (score 0):

I run a dualboot system Ubuntu 20.04/ Windows 10.

I encountered the same conditions here. Having verified the hash of the .iso before using Rufus to create a LiveUSB, I think I can rule out a corrupted download.

This fix worked like a charm:
https://www.stephenwagner.com/2019/05/05/ubuntu-linux-black-screen-frozen-system-after-upgrade-install/

> #### Temporary Fix
>
> To get the system to boot:
>
> 1. After turning on your PC, hold the right SHIFT key to get to the GRUB bootloader if your computer uses a BIOS. If your computer uses EFI or UEFI, continuously tap the <kbd>ESC</kbd> (escape) key after turning on your PC.
> 2. Once GRUB is open, press the <kbd>e</kbd> key to edit the first highlighted entry “Ubuntu”.
> 3. Move your cursor down to the line that starts with `linux`, and use the right arrow key to find the section with the words `ro quiet splash`.
> 4. Add `nomodeset` after these words.
> 5. Feel free to remove `quiet` and `splash` for more verbosity to troubleshoot the boot process.
> 6. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
> 7. The system should now boot.
>
> #### Permanent Fix
>
> To permanently resolve the issue:
>
> 1. Once the system has booted using the temporary fix, log in.
> 2. Open a terminal window (Applications -> Terminal, or press the “Start” button and type terminal).
> 3. [...] Use `sudo` to open your favorite text editor and edit the file `/etc/default/grub`
>
>    ```
>    sudo nano /etc/default/grub
>    ```
> 4. Locate the line with the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and add `nomodeset` to the variables. Feel free to remove `splash` and `quiet` if you’d like text boot. Here’s an example of my line after editing (yours may look different):
>
>    ```
>    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
>    ```
> 5. Save the file and exit the text editor (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to quit, the press <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd> to save).
> 6. At the bash prompt, execute the following command to regenerate the `grub.conf` file in `/boot` from your new default file:
>
>    ```
>    sudo update-grub
>    ```
> 7. Restart your system, it should now boot!
>
> Please Note: Always make sure you have a full system backup before modifying any system files!